# Can we show the title hover over x axis/y axis text in highcharts dumbbell chart?

Tags: highcharts

We to show the title (full name of x-axis label name) like :
[![textoverhoverofx-axis lebel][1]][1]
Can we achieve it in Highcharts ?

new spac : [![Y-axixlebel][2]][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6sjQ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Os3.png

Here in second spac we are not showing full name and want to show full name over hover of label.

Comment: Hi @Thakurlal Pandey, Please describe the problem more precisely. Could you for example create a mock visualisation with a bigger context?

Comment: We have very long name on y-axix  and  sowing small text as xyz...  to make design good and want to show full name on hover of the name in x axix/y axis

Comment: updated the question also please check it once

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `useHTML` option, use a formatter function for labels to return the proper HTML structure and style the custom tooltip by CSS.

JS:

```
labels: {
  useHTML: true,
  formatter: function() {
    var shortText = this.value.toString().substring(0, 20) + '...';
    return `
        <div class="labelTooltip">${shortText}
            <span class="labelTooltipText">${this.value}</span>
        </div>
    `
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.labelTooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.labelTooltip .labelTooltipText {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.labelTooltip:hover .labelTooltipText {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ytqjuozp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter